# Parked domain htaccess rewrite WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, dns

Website https://www.example.com has a parked domain https://www.example.be.
The site uses SSL and visitors are redirected to the secured version.

However, when a visitor types in the browser example.be he/she is redirected to https://www.example.com instead of https://www.example.be.

Htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

How to redirect domain.be (and al subsequend pages etc) to https://www.example.be instead of https://www.example.com?

Comment: That .htaccess doesn't have anything to do with redirects...

Comment: So you think the problem is not in the .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that adding the following rules to .htaccess made it possible:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.be [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.be/$1 [L,R=301]
```